# Knitting pdf doc from R markdown with stargazer output

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer

I'm trying to get stargazer output(latex format) of logistic regression. I can successfully get a pretty output by this code.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Kenta Okuyama"
date: "2018年5月10日"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

## Table2
```{r,results='asis', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(stargazer)
load("C:/Users/kenta/Documents/R_Pojects/HealthPlace/.RData")

MultilogitSlowCon<- glm(hbp_treat~E2FCASlowPHC_m+gender+age+BMI+smoke_bi+drink_bi+incomeMean,data=dflogisticLW,subset=age>=30,family = "binomial"(link="logit"))

stargazer(MultilogitSlowCon,title="E2FCA Slow decay 
(Continuous)",dep.var.labels=c("Uncontrolled 
hypertension"),ci=TRUE,ci.level=0.95,single.row=TRUE)
```
````

But when I added align=TRUE in the code of stargazer

```
stargazer(MultilogitSlowCon,title="E2FCA Slow decay 
(Continuous)",dep.var.labels=c("Uncontrolled 
hypertension"),ci=TRUE,ci.level=0.95,single.row=TRUE,align=TRUE)
```

I can no longer get pdf output, it returns the error.

```
You are recommended to install the tinytex package to build PDF.FALSE
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (MiKTeX 2.9.6670 64-bit)
entering extended mode
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
```

I appreciate if anyone ever ran into this kind of issue, and help me with it. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you installed the `tinytex` package like the message recommends? Also, I think we may need to see the contents of `MultilogitSlowCon` to solve this, please add it as a reproducible example.

Comment: @Marius Thank you so much for your comment. I apologize that I missed the line for contents of MultilogitSlowCon. I added in the original post. And I overlooked the message for tinytex package. I will try to research about it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: An alternative (I'm shilling for my own package) is `huxtable::huxreg(MultilogitSlowCon)` which gives you back a table that you can reformat at will and prints out LaTeX automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, they now added the answer to the documentation. Add `\usepackage{dcolumn}` to your LaTeX-preamble and it should work just fine.